# How can I find similar correspond points in ICP transformation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I have 2 set of point clouds and read them with this code in Matlab:

```
ptCloud1 = pcread('sub2a.ply');
ptCloud2 = pcread('sub2b.ply');
```

then register the second one with the first one with icp (iterative closest point) algorithm like this:

```
[tform,movingReg,rmse] = pcregrigid(ptCloud2,ptCloud1)
```

the answer in 'movingReg'.
Now the question is how can I know which point in the point cloud of 'movingReg' is the corresponding similar point of the point cloud of 'ptCloud1'?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact implementation of matlab's ICP. But the simplest case is creating a KDTree from target to source to then making queries for each point. I will give a general code in Python and I hope can you use that in Matlab as well.

Using scipy,

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

def find_correspondences(source_points, target_points):
    tree = KDTree(target_points)
    correspondences_index = []

    for point in source_points:
        _, idx = tree.query(point)
        target_point_index = idx
        correspondences_index.append(target_point_index)

    return correspondences_index
```

Now, `correspondences_index` lists holds the mapping between each point. Basically, correspondences_index[0] would give the corresponding point of the first point in the source. Then you can add the same color for both corresponding target & source points to visualize them.